# Link Thumbnail from files draw into shapes with TImage component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

I'm trying to link the thumbnail of an images created within a circle shape at runtime to a timage component for an Firemonkey app, any idea of how i can show the image selected on the shape ?

Comment: If you're using Delphi and Firemonkey, then you're clearly not using FreePascal. Please do not tag spam. Use only the tags that actually apply to your question. Tags have specific meaning and functionality here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to create a TImageControl at run time, load it with an image and center it on a TCircle shape:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ImageControl : TImageControl;
    Previous     : TComponent;
begin
    Previous := FindComponent(Circle1.Name + '_ThumbImage');
    if Previous is TImageControl then
        ImageControl := TImageControl(Previous)
    else begin
        ImageControl              := TImageControl.Create(Self);
        ImageControl.Name         := Circle1.Name + '_ThumbImage';
        ImageControl.Size.Width   := Circle1.Size.Width / 2;
        ImageControl.Size.Height  := Circle1.Size.Height / 2;
        ImageControl.Parent       := Circle1;
        ImageControl.Position.X   := (Circle1.Size.Width - ImageControl.Size.Width) / 2;
        ImageControl.Position.Y   := (Circle1.Size.Height - ImageControl.Size.Height) / 2;
        ImageControl.Visible      := TRUE;
    end;
    ImageControl.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('MyThumbnail.jpg');
end;
```

Of course, instead of loading an image from a file, you can load the thumbnail you created. You didn't said where your thumbnail is stored so I assumed it is in a file...